# Why does adding '*' to a MySQL query cause a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In MySQL, this code works fine:

```
select f, blegg.* from blegg limit 1;

+------+------+------+------+
| f    | f    | g    | h    |
+------+------+------+------+
|   17 |   17 |    2 |   17 |
+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So why does this code cause a syntax error?

```
select f, * from blegg limit 1;

-- * is unqualified
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* 
from blegg limit 1' at line 1
```

I've looked through the manual but didn't really find anything.  Why does `select <field>, * ...` fail where `select <field>, <table>.* ...` and `select * ...` and `select *, <field> ...` succeed?

Comment: I can't explain why.  But I know Oracle does the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MySQL manual lays all this out pretty clearly in the section on [`SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

> - A select list consisting only of a single unqualified `*` can be used as
>     shorthand to select all columns from all tables:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ...
>   ```
> - `tbl_name.*` can be used as a
>     qualified shorthand to select all columns from the named table:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ...
>   ```
> - Use of an unqualified `*`
>     with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To
>     avoid this problem, use a qualified `tbl_name.*` reference
>
>   ```
>   SELECT AVG(score), t1.* FROM t1 ...
>   ```

The documentation seems to indicate that `*` by itself is only valid in the special case where it's the only thing in the select list. However, it only says using an unqualified `*` with other items *may* produce a parse error.

Beyond MySQL, the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (old, but linkable) says as much:

> ```
> 7.9  <query specification>
>
>          Format
>
>          <query specification> ::=
>               SELECT [ <set quantifier> ] <select list> <table expression>
>
>          <select list> ::=
>                 <asterisk>
>               | <select sublist> [ { <comma> <select sublist> }... ]
>
>          <select sublist> ::=
>                 <derived column>
>               | <qualifier> <period> <asterisk>
>
>          <derived column> ::= <value expression> [ <as clause> ]
>
>          <as clause> ::= [ AS ] <column name>
> ```

`<select list>` can either be `<asterisk>` by itself *or* a "normal" select list.

Comment: `select *, count(*) ...` succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

but

```
select *, f from blegg
```

will work fine.

Possibly an unqualified * has to appear as the first expression in the select?

Answer (score -2):

Possibly because you're selecting the same field twice. In the following query

```
select name, * from <...>
```

the `*` will include `name`, so you're explicitly specifying `name` a second time.

This isn't a convincing argument because the following is valid:

```
select name, name from <...>
```

and so is the following

```
select name, users.* from users
```

both of which will select the same field multiple times.

More likely it is simply a syntax limitation of MySQL.

Comment: no, that's not it:  `select count(*), * from blegg` also fails

Comment: But, his first, working, example does the same thing (and does include `f` twice in the output).

Comment: This isn't a great answer, but it was too long/complex for a comment. Will happily delete if/when somebody provides a more concrete explanation.